# Detecting which PDFs or Images contain handwritting?

Tags: python, pdf

I wanted to throw out a question in hopes someone can point me in the right direction.

If I have a group of PDFs or images.  Some PDFs are textual content. There is no problem.

Some PDFs might have handwritten notes that I need to OCR.

The problem is finding which PDFs have handwriting.

Maybe that is not possible. Or maybe it is nothing better than looking for all PDFs that contain an image (Although that may not be very precise because PDFs can have just legit images embedded).

The OCR side I have scripts in Python. The problem is knowing what to OCR exactly.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you know the kinds of fonts or font-families within your document, you could train a neural network to detect handwriting or typed letters. By creating images of the pages within the PDFs you can then scan each page in slices through the detector. Letter cutoffs would be OK, since this is mainly meant for quick and dirty detection. Once your network produces a signal that's above a given threshold on a given slice, you label that slice / page accordingly. This solution may not be the fastest, but it will work and be fairly accurate. The difficulty may be creating the training dataset